# MySql Select IF determine what condition should be implemented

Tags: mysql

I have two condition for my query, if count(a.id) is more than 1, than  the where condition is DAYS LIKE '%2%' or else DAYS LIKE '%6%'. But I have no idea how to perform this. I have tried that query bellow, but it wrongs.

Can anyone help me? thanks.

Ps. Sorry for my English.

```
SET @time = '20:59:59';

SELECT *
FROM `msshift` a
WHERE IF(
        a.`TIMEFROM` < a.`TIMETO`,
        CAST(@time AS TIME) BETWEEN a.`TIMEFROM` AND a.`TIMETO`,
        (CAST(@time AS TIME) BETWEEN CAST('00:00:00' AS TIME) AND a.`TIMETO`) OR 
        (CAST(@time AS TIME) BETWEEN a.`TIMEFROM` AND CAST('24:00:00' AS TIME))
    ) = 1 AND PLANT = '1011' AND IF(COUNT(a.ID) > 1, a.DAYS LIKE '%2%', a.DAYS LIKE '%6%')
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't use aggregate functions in a where clause.  This is what the 'having' clause is designed for.

I can't tell what the specific query would be without seeing the structure and knowing what result your aiming for but here's an example.

table: foo
id: INT
foreign_id: INT
name: CHAR

```
SELECT count(*) as grouped_count from foo
GROUP BY foreign_id
HAVING grouped_count > 5
```

This will return every group of records, belonging to the foreign table, that has more than 5 records in its group.

Hope this helps.